# Resetting administrator password on Windows server 2008 R2 over Raid

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, raid, password-recovery, password-reset

I have locked both my administrator accounts out on my Windows Server 2008 R2 that has Raid. I tried the following-

- Insert the original Windows Server 2008 installation DVD
- Reset the computer, boot from DVD
- Choose option “Repair your computer”
- Start command prompt
- `C:`
- `CD C:\Windows\System32`
- `MOVE Utilman.exe Utilman.exe.bak`
- `COPY Cmd.exe Utilman.exe`
- You may also need to “Enable” the administrator account which can be done by using `NET USER administrator /active:yes`
- Restart Windows
- At the login screen, type <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>; this fires up cmd.exe now
- `NET USER administrator newAdminPasswdHere` Presto! Login as administrator!
- Now repair computer again and move the original Utilman.exe back

My problem is that since my server is on Raid when I am at the command prompt from the dvd the cmd prompt does not recognized the c drive.. it says "the system cannot find the drive specified."

Does anyone know how to get it to find the C: drive, or any other way I can get into my admin account?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that RAID 0 is a terrible idea. Is this software RAID or hardware RAID?

Comment: It's actually Raid 5 sorry and it's the hardward Raid..

Comment: In either case, you need to provide the RAID driver during setup. During Windows setup, when you get to the screen asking which drive to install to, there is a button "Add Driver". After that, don't click next.You can press F12 (I think) to get a command prompt and finish your instructions.

Comment: So after seletcing enlish for the language I'm supposed to go to "Repair your computer" right? and then I can go to the system recovery tools which is where I can find the command prompt.. I didn't see anything that you could "Add driver" but there was something that said 'Load drivers" and after you click that it tells you to insert media for the device and click ok... Or are you saying that after I select the lanuage I should click "install now" instead of "repair you computer"? I just don't want to mess anything up... :/

Comment: Protecting this since anything with 'password' in a tag is a spam-magnet. Please, continue.

Comment: I can only access the boot drive in the command prompt after selecting "repair your computer" Is there anything I can do with the boot drive? any .exe or .dll files I can excute or open? I really need to be able to access this server.. I really dont want to have to rebuild it.

Comment: @John Homer -Can you explain the process that you mentioned above? I just want to make sure I'm doing exactly what you are suggesting. I think I know what you are talking about but there aren't any drives to choose from like it doesn't recognize anything because of the Raid..

Answer (score 1):

I always use [Windows Password Resetter](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) to do stuff like this.  It works well enough to blank the Adminstrator password (allowing you to reset it on next login).  The bootable Live CD can usually see most drives I deal with (provided I am using real, bona-fide hardware RAID).

Haven't had to try it on Win7/2008R2 yet, though -- might be some restrictions built into those operating systems regarding logging in with blank passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Backtrack will do this for you.  It can be downloaded [here](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/).